# Is Rust multi-dimensional array row major and tightly packed?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, row-major-order, column-major-order

I'm writing a 3D math library for my project, I want to know is the Rust column major or row major? For example I have a 2 dimensional array as matrix and I want to serve it to a C library (like OpenGL or Vulkan), for those library this is important to have a tightly packed column major array.

Comment: For OpenGL  and Vulkan you can specify using `layout` in the shader whether your data is row-major or column-major.

Comment: I'm new to vulkan but for OpenGL it is recommended to place your matrix elements in column major order.

Comment: Rust has wrappers for OpenGL (glium) and Vulkan (Volkano I think) that you should probably use instead of directly using the APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, let's find out:

```
let arr: [[i8; 2]; 2] = [[1, 2], [8, 9]];

println!(
    "{:?} {:?} {:?} {:?}", 
    &arr[0][0] as *const _,
    &arr[0][1] as *const _,
    &arr[1][0] as *const _,
    &arr[1][1] as *const _,
);
```

Prints `0x7fff5584ae74 0x7fff5584ae75 0x7fff5584ae76 0x7fff5584ae77` for example. So: yes these arrays with length known to compile time are tightly packed and (considering the common definition of the terms) row major.

*Note:* the test above doesn't say that this *always* works! You can read more about this topic [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html).

**But:** usually you use heap allocated arrays since you can't know the length beforehand. For that purpose it's idiomatic to use `Vec`. But there are no special rules for this type, so `Vec<Vec<T>>` is **not** tightly packed! For that reason `Vec<Vec<T>>` is *not* idiomatic anymore -- you should use a simple `Vec<T>` and do the calculation of the index yourself.

Of course, writing the indexing calculation multiple times is not a good solution either. Instead, you should define some wrapper type which does the indexing for you. But as Sebastian Redl already mentioned: you are not the only one having this problem and there exist types exactly for this purpose already.

Comment: Tnx, I defined my matrix as: type Mat4x4<T> = [[T; 4]; 4]; i'm not using Vec for it.